# php uploaded file does not exist

Tags: php, upload

I've made sure that the /tmp folder is writeable, and in php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 5M
post_max_size = 8M
```

and in my upload.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and in my upload_file.php

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] , '/var/www/html/web' );
  }
?>
```

This is the output

```
Upload: screenshot 2013-12-30 15:00:54.png
Type: image/png
Size: 201.8154296875 kB
Stored in: /tmp/phpEdIgXr
```

but /tmp/phpEdIgXr  does not exist!

Comment: How do you know? Does a `file_exists($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])` really return `false`?

Comment: what do you mean by does not exist?

Comment: I checked in the filesystem of the server, and the file is not available. Earlier, I attempted to perform a move on a more complicated application, but I tried this as the base case. It failed.

Comment: thats a temp file. it gets deleted when the php process stops. you need to copy the contents of the file to a permanent location.

Comment: Remember, the temp file gets DELETED immediately once the script is completely executed. In order to keep it, move it somewhere else.

Comment: I have updated my script, and it still does not work

Comment: Use `'web'` instead of `'/var/www/html/web'` if `web` is the folder you are storing your files in, and while running your script from the root. Which 9 times out of 10 is the issue, setting an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Comment: check your directory permission and also path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put below code and try. it might be helpful to you.

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Apologies, an error has occurred.";
        echo "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    }
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"[YOUR FOLDER PATH]".$_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to specify the file name after the destination path.

Answer (score 0):

For any upload files to surface in a directory, you need to `chmod 777` that folder.

Comment: Friends dont let other friends 777 their upload folders for security reasons ;) Giving PHP permission to write on a folder takes combination of chmod and chown. So owner of that folder should be web server (usally www-data if Apache) or cgi, so chmod 755 will be just enough.